# Html select (dropdown) works only in postback, why?

Tags: html, asp.net, postback, html-select

I have html select in ASP.NET. this line:

```
<select id="s4" runat="server"multiple="true"class="s4a"style="height:50px">
```

now, the problem is when I load the page, I can't open the dropdown. it is kind locked.
when I do form submit (press button), the dropdown is open, and I can choose now.
this is the part from the code behind, where i get all data into select:

```
 s4.DataSource = dpDb.AllTexts;
 s4.DataBind();
 s4.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

by the way, I have the same in other page, and it works.

is someone have an idea why it works like that ?

Comment: do you bind this data on page load as well ?

Comment: s4.ClearSelection(); try this code

Comment: i bind the data every load. i will try "s4.ClearSelection();" now

Comment: there is no option like ClearSelection() :-(

Comment: there is data binding for sure, because i can see the first index name.
the problem is that i can't open the dropdown (html select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the specific answer, so i solved it by redirect to the same page with GET/POST IN ANY "SelectedIndexChanged" with the selected index, and handle it in the code.